# Blank node in forest edges library

Tags: forest

I am making a tree with package `forest`. This is so far what I've tried from the example in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/forest/forest-doc.pdf#subsection.4.2) -

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=south,draw},
forked edges,
[[First node][Second node[Third node][Fourth node[Fifth node][Sixth node]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

If we look at the output of it, the first node has a box in which nothing is there. I don't want that box, but I want the line below the box. How to achieve this?

[image: Current output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `draw=none` to specific nodes to overrule the `draw` that applies to all nodes (because it is set in `for tree`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=south,draw},
forked edges,
[,draw=none
 [First node]
 [Second node
  [Third node]
  [Fourth node
   [Fifth node]
   [Sixth node]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. What was the key? I suppose `[,draw=none` made the change, right?

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Niranjan The reason it happens is because you have `for tree= ... draw`, which draws the border of all nodes. You could just not draw this one, so you wouldn't have to cancel it. Or you could test and only draw nodes with content. Alternatively, you might want to use `coordinate` for empty nodes, so they don't take up spurious space (or you may not, if the space isn't spurious).